# Why does the file not to be filled if I don't close the stream?

Tags: java, io, stream, writer

I have to read a data from one file, and write it in other file in a reverse order and in lowercase.

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
List<String> s = new LinkedList<>();
String temp;
while ((temp = r.readLine()) != null)
     s.add(temp);
r.close();
BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file1.txt"));
ListIterator<String> li = s.listIterator(s.size());
while (li.hasPrevious()) {
     w.write(li.previous().toLowerCase() + "\n");
}
// w.close();
```

If I comment the last string, the file will remain empty; otherwise the file will be filled properly. Could you please explain me why does it happen?

Comment: Calling `close` will also flush the stream, which is needed. See [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close--)

Comment: That’s what you request explicitly when you ask for a *buffered* writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are chaining the output through a `BufferedWriter`. The `BufferedWriter` buffers output, keeping it in memory until one of these conditions occur:

- The write buffer is full
- `flush` is called
- The writer is closed

When one of these conditions occur, the `BufferedWriter` will write the buffered data to the underlying medium (in your case a file).

Answer (score 2):

Because you have all lines ended up in the internal buffer, which is not flushed because close() is not called.